# Any subspace of connected set is connected?

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ is connected set and $B\subset A$.

Is $B$ connected?

Also is $\emptyset$ (empty set) connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $\Bbb R$ is connected; is $\{0,1\}$?

The empty set is both compact and connected; this follows immediately from the definitions. First, $\varnothing$ is finite, and every finite set is clearly compact. Secondly, $\varnothing$ cannot be partitioned into two non-empty sets at all, let alone two non-empty separated sets. (Note that some people apply the notion of connectedness only to non-empty sets; for them $\varnothing$ is neither connected nor disconnected.)

Comment: Is $\phi$ connected or compact or neither?

Comment: @Jake: I’ve extended the answer to cover the other question.

Comment: Last question: Is $[0,1]\cup[3,4]$ closed and is $(1,2]$ closed, open or either?

Comment: @Jake: (To get $\cup$, use `\cup`.) The first is closed, the second is neither.

Comment: oh, ok thanks I get it now.

Comment: @Jake: You’re welcome.

Comment: some consider $\emptyset$ to be not connected, nor disconnected, much like the status of $1$ and primality. The reason is that some theorem become a bit cleaner to state (e.g., a space is then the union of connected subspaces, uniquely up to an ordering of the subspaces).

Comment: @Ittay: I’m aware of that, but (a) I don’t like it, and (b) in my experience it’s less common at the elementary level than the purely definitional approach. However, for completeness I probably should add it to my answer.